# Kotlin coroutines crash with no helpful stacktrace

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

My Android app crashes and I see this stack trace in Logcat. It doesn't tell me which line of code is causing the problem.

```
2021-05-05 09:13:33.143 1069-1069/com.mycompany.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.mycompany.app, PID: 1069
  retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 403 
    at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Is there a way to map this back to my code, to see which call to retrofit is causing it? I have a repository with code like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getSomeData(): Stuff {
   return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val body = myRetroApi.getStuff()
      ...
```

Do I need to wrap every `withContext` body to make sure no `Throwables` escape? I thought that if something threw an exception there, it would log an error, not crash the entire app.

**Edit**

I messed up when asking this question and put the emphasis on wrong things. So I'm removing the "retrofit" tag. It turns out the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` call does re-throw the `Exception` as expected, but when the exception gets back up to `viewModelScope.launch`, if that block does not catch it, the app crashes.

Comment: `I thought that if something threw an exception there, it would log an error, not crash the entire app.` that's a bold assumption to make :)

Comment: Yes, I guess so, though it's based on similar experience with server-side Java and background threads. It's not the _crash_ that surprises me that much; it's more that the stack trace doesn't point to anything in my code.

Comment: for coroutines you need to provide your own error handling, you can find a lot regarding this if you just do some research, people typically make use of a `safeApiCall` wrapper to execute coroutine calls and return results

Comment: in general though, i'd say probably _most_ frameworks for android require you to handle exceptions yourself, if you don't add error handling for rxjava it will also crash, depending on how you use it i suppose

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is it normal for the stack trace to not point to your code at all? I'm not used to that, but maybe that's standard with coroutines?

Comment: no idea regarding that

Comment: Coroutine exception handling is really complicated and it's hard to remember all the weird rules about its behavior. My advice is to catch possible exceptions at the lowest possible point and wrap them using a result-wrapping sealed class, which is the Kotlin alternative to Java's checked exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception is not handled the app will crash of course.

You can add a try catch to avoid this:

```
suspend fun getSomeData() {
   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      try{
        val body = myRetroApi.getStuff()
        ...
      } catch (e : Exception){
         //your code
      }
...
```

Comment: How would you propagate an exception from within the `withContext` to `getSomeData`? If that's not possible, then I guess change the return type of getSomeData from `T` to something like `T?` or `Result<T>`.

Comment: @RobN Yes, it is up to you to decide how to represent that. Something like `Result<T>` sounds like a good option. That way you don't lose the error information.

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit is giving you a 403 Unauthorized HTTP exception. It may be that the server isn't passing any additional error message or that you need to catch HttpException and check for the message. In either case, this isn't a Retrofit issue hence it's just passing the error it's getting from the server you're calling.

It's best to create a network result wrapper and a wrapper function for API calls to handle exceptions.

You can do something like this. Keep in mind, the actual implementation is completely up to you. I would however suggest using runCatching when it comes to couroutines as it handles cancellation exceptions.

```
 sealed class NetworkResult<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : NetworkResult<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable, val message: String?) : NetworkResult<Nothing>()
 }
```

```
    suspend fun networkCall(): String = ""
```

```
suspend fun <T> safeApiCall(block: suspend () -> T): NetworkResult<T> {

    return runCatching {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            block()
        }
    }.fold({
        NetworkResult.Success(it)
    }, {
        when (it) {
            is HttpException -> NetworkResult.Error(it, "Network error")
            else -> NetworkResult.Error(it, "Some other message...")
            // else -> throw it
        }
    })
}
```

```
suspend fun getData() {
    val result: NetworkResult<String> = safeApiCall {
        networkCall()
    }
    when (result) {
        is NetworkResult.Success -> {
            //Handle success
        }
        is NetworkResult.Error -> { //Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

runCatching uses Kotlin's built-in Result class and there are several ways of handling the result. These are just a few.

```
    runCatching {
        //.....
    }.getOrElse { throwable ->
        //handle exception
    }

    runCatching {
        //.....
    }.getOrThrow()

    runCatching {

    }.onSuccess {

    }.onFailure {

    }
```